# How many types of Achara or Acharana are there?

Tags: practice

I think Sadachar, Durachar etc. are parts of Acharas or Acharana. I don't know them all. I would like to know,

How many types of Achara are there?

How are they described in scriptures?

I will be happy if example is given for each Achara.

Comment: sadachar and durachar just means good practice and bad practice and not part of any practice. Achar = practice. There are many practices prescribed for each type of person like a student, preceptor, king etc., adding them is a too broad question.